# Pushing elements from JSON to a nested array [i][push here]

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have 2 files: index.js, and list.json

I want to take an element from list.json and add it into the nested array using the following structure: [hour][visits per hour]

hour points to the index of the hour, so for ex: hour 12 is actually index 12. The problem is I keep getting undefined tags in the console. I will post it at the bottom to show you what I mean.

Here is an excerpt from the json file, there are 28 lines in total:

```
[
  { "time":"01:34:19", "visits": 37 },
  { "time":"02:03:21", "visits": 42 },
  { "time":"02:22:35", "visits": 51 },
  { "time":"02:43:54", "visits": 31 },
  { "time":"03:31:43", "visits": 24 },
  { "time":"03:38:01", "visits": 27 },
  { "time":"05:29:57", "visits": 36 },
  { "time":"05:54:08", "visits": 47 },
  { "time":"06:11:17", "visits": 49 },
  { "time":"07:22:03", "visits": 51 },
  { "time":"07:27:09", "visits": 55 },
]
```

Here is Javascript attempt:

```
let json = require('./list.json');

let visitsPerHr = [];
visitsPerHr.length = 24;

//I had to do this to avoid a type error in the 2nd loop
for (let x = 0; x < 24; x++) {
    visitsPerHr[x] = x;
}

let hour = -1;
let visitCount = -1;

for(let i = 0; i < json.length; i++){

    //get hour & parse
    hour = json[i].time[0] + json[i].time[1];
    hour = parseInt(hour, 10);

    //get visits and parse
    visitCount = json[i].visits;
    visitCount = parseInt(visitCount, 10);

    //push to the hour(index) the number of visits, later i need to reorder 
    //the visits based on highest amount if multiple ones exist within that hour.

    visitsPerHr[hour].push = visitCount;

}
```

I need help pushing the visitCount to the relevant hour (index.) So upon looping each index(hours start from 1 to 23, I should be able to get all the visits for that index.

An example of the result i am seeking for hour 7: [7][27,29,22]

here is my current result:

```
2
undefined
2
undefined
2
undefined
2
undefined
5
undefined
6
undefined
6
undefined
6
undefined
6
undefined
7
undefined
7
undefined
7
undefined
7
undefined
7
undefined
8
undefined
9
undefined
10
```

and so on it goes till 23

Comment: Three things that immediately caught my eye: (1) no JSON.parse() anywhere; (2) what is that array-access and the addition of `time` values supposed to do? (3) `visitsPerHr[hour].push = visitCount;` doesn't seem to make sense, shouldn't it be `visitsPerHr[hour] = visitCount;`?

Comment: Hi dommson, thank you so much for your prompt reply. 1: I am not so familiar with JSON/JS just trying my best, should that be a single line?

Comment: How many visits are there per hour? It will also be helpful if you post the code at list.json, because how the module is exported also matters.

Comment: Hi, Addis, Thanks for trying to help... I am struggling badly with this. I updated the json above in my original post to reflect what the entire json file looks like.

adding visits to a total sum per hour is not an option for me,

Comment: Keep in mind that adding visits to a total sum per hour is not an option, because I still have to break it up by the minute, as you see there can be multiple ones visits counts per hour (doesn't matter if their unique or not.) I didn't add the minute code because I didn't write it yet, but thats ok because once I understand how to add elements to a nested array, I should apply that knowledge else to minutes as well :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
const json = require('./list.json');
const visitsPerHour = {0:0,1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0 ... 23:0};
for (let element of json) {
    visitsPerHour[(new Date(element.time)).getHours()] += element.visits;
}
```

Comment: Hi Itay, thanks a lot :) I appreciate you taking a crack at it. I decided to simplify my intentions: This is what I'm looking for I have:

a parentArray and dataArray, I want to push each letter to a nested array inside the parentArray. At the end each number should have 1 letter inside its nested array.

parentArray = [1,2,3]
dataArray = [a,b,c]

for(let i = 0, i < parentArray.length; i++){
      parentArray[i].push(dataArray[i]);
}

This is what I want to accomplish, it simply comes down to this.